# python can not use .pgpass while connecting to PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql

I can not use .pgpass file while connecting to postgresql db using python script(((
My python script to connect is without password:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='postgres' user='postgres' host='192.168.136.129'");
```

My **.pgpass:**

```
*:*:*:postgres:password
```

is located in **/var/lib/postgresql** - home directory for postgres user.
However when I connect to db locally:

```
psql -U postgres
```

no password is asked. But for python error is raised:

```
root@debian:/python_codes/Junior/Level1/DB1/Generator_py# python connect_db.py 
Unable to connect to db...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "connect_db.py", line 34, in connectdb
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='postgres' user='postgres' host='192.168.136.129'");
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 179, in connect
    connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

Comment: The .pgpass file must be in the home directory of the user launching the script.

Comment: Script is launched on another server.

Comment: If the script is indeed on the another server then I suggest you copy `.pgpass` file to the home directory of the UNIX user running the script on another server.

Comment: I coped file in all directories: the same result. Locally it works: no password is asked, but python script does not work(((

Answer (score 4):

Based on the prompt from this output:

> root@debian:/python_codes/Junior/Level1/DB1/Generator_py# python
>   connect_db.py

you're running the commmand as Unix user `root`, so the corresponding `.pgpass` file must be located in root's `HOME` directory, which means not `/var/lib/postgresql` but probably `/root` or `/`

Also its permissions must be restricted to readable by the owner, that is, `chmod 600 $HOME/.pgpass`

Answer (score 0):

To prevent user from launching pg_dump with a permanent `.pgpass` or use `PGPASSWORD` in command, one could create .pgpass just before `pg_dump` starts and delete it off 3 seconds later (inside a compiled program).

```
subprocess.Popen(echo 'hostname:port:database:username:password' > /home/user/.pgpass, shell=True).wait()

subprocess.Popen(echo 'sleep 3; rm /home/user/.pgpass; rm /home/user/remove-pgpass.sh' > /home/user/remove-pgpass.sh, shell=True).wait()

subprocess.Popen(chmod 600 /home/user/.pgpass, shell=True).wait()

subprocess.Popen(chmod +x /home/user/remove-pgpass.sh, shell=True).wait()

subprocess.Popen(/home/user/remove-pgpass.sh, shell=True)

subprocess.Popen(pg_dump -h localhost -d user-db -U db-admin > mydbdump.sql, shell=True).wait()
```