# How to connect to postgres with password given in .pgpass file?

Tags: linux, postgresql, authentication, psql

I have my .pgpass file in home/centos directory with 0600 permission.

```
10.43.11.123:5432:mydb:postgres:abcd@1234
```

(The real password contains a backslash character.)

I have tried all the ways given in this [link](https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2014/03/23/how-to-non-interactively-provide-password-for-the-postgresql-interactive-terminal/)

Nothing works.

I tried the solution provided in [python can not use .pgpass while connecting to PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28931828/python-can-not-use-pgpass-while-connecting-to-postgresql) but that does not help either

Every time it gives error:

> psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

I also tried:

```
psql -h 10.43.11.123 -d mydb -U postgres
```

It prompts:

> psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
>   password retrieved from file "/home/centos/.pgpass"

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html):

> If an entry needs to contain `:` or `\`, escape this character with `\`.

Since you say that the password contains a backslash character, the solution is to double that backslash.